# Using Wildcards To Grab ID Name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to iterate an array of gridviews and check if it is checked.  My grids are set-up like so

```
var dgvAr = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"];
```

And the naming conventions are like such

```
Test1_checkboxMe_1
Test1_checkboxMe_2

Test2_checkboxMe_1
Test2_checkboxMe_2
```

And I use this syntax, but I get an error of

> Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

How should the below syntax be altered so it can read the value?

```
/////////
var chk = $('[id*=' + dgvAr[i] + ']').find('input[type="checkbox"][id*=' + dgvAr[i] + '_checkboxMe_]').each(function () {
if (chk.val()) {
```

////////

Comment: Is there no way you can use common classes and loop through them? It would certainly tidy up your code, not to mention make it shorter.

Comment: `chk` is used before its defined, the code in the `.each` callback executes before it returns.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You're trying to use the variable `chk` in the function that tries to *define* `chk`.  What exactly are you expecting to be in that variable?  The `.each()` function passes a reference to the items it's iterating over to the function: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: @David - I am wanting to iterate each checkbox in the array of grids and if they are checked, then add to an array, if they are not checked, then omit them.

Comment: In that case you don't need a loop, just the `:checked` selector.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I was originally using the if ($(this).is(':checked')) { syntax, however this was ignoring the checked value

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:checked` to find checked checkboxes;

```
$("#Test1 input[type='checkbox']:checked")
```

Comment: I was originally using if ($(this).is(':checked')) { but it was ignoring if the value was checked or not

Comment: You should debug your code. Obviously, there is a problem with your grid selectors.

Comment: I do not follow.  What is the issue with grid selectors?